# Div not going to the bottom of site

Tags: html, css

so I'm coding my site and I need the DIV to fill the height of the page completely

However when someone zooms out, it goes like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq2ZQ.jpg

I was wondering if there was a fix to this? I know I can use height: 100% or something but I prefer to keep it on auto as it makes the site responsive.

http://hastebin.com/ikoyefumif.xml < If you need part of the code, here it is. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `min-height: 100vh`? This will set a minimum height of 100% of the height of the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst `min-height: 100vh` works in some cases, it does not in all.

Have a go at using this:

```
#parent {
    position: absolute;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I advise you play around with the directional values depending on what you wish, and you may have to alter the value too.

Here's a demonstation: https://jsfiddle.net/joshcrowe/u1wc7zcn/1/

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    background-color: purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```